# Update Image File with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, upload

Help me to update data (image file), there is 4 input type for file

If i update image 1 and 2, image 3 and 4 will have the same name with image 2

But if i update again to image 3 and 4, image 1 and 2 will be lost

**Information:** Image 1: `$lname`, Image 2: `$mname`, Image 3: `$nname` and Image 4: `$oname`.

There is my 
**Controller**

```
$this->upload->do_upload('k');
$hasil = $this->upload->data();
$k = $this->upload->data();
$kname = $k['file_name'];

if ($lname == '') {
    $this->upload->do_upload('l');
    $l = $this->upload->data();
    $lname = $l['file_name'];
}
if ($mname == '') {
    $this->upload->do_upload('m');
    $m = $this->upload->data();
    $mname = $m['file_name'];
}
if ($nname == '') {
    $this->upload->do_upload('n');
    $n = $this->upload->data();
    $nname = $n['file_name'];
}
if ($oname == '') {
    $this->upload->do_upload('o');
    $o = $this->upload->data();
    $oname = $o['file_name'];
}
$data = array('gambar' => $hasil['file_name'],
    'gambar1' => $lname,
    'ket_gambar1' => $this->input->post('c'),
    'gambar2' => $mname,
    'ket_gambar2' => $this->input->post('d'),
    'gambar3' => $nname,
    'ket_gambar3' => $this->input->post('e'),
    'gambar4' => $oname,
    'ket_gambar4' => $this->input->post('f')
);
```

Comment: It's a little confusing! Why don't you explain your problem a little more, and maybe provide more information and code?!

Answer (score 1):

Well my friend, you need to modify your code to handle multiple uploads. 
What i see in here is just single file upload being carried out. Rather, there can be code something like this.. (assuming you keep the same name for all the files being uploaded [upl_files])

```
$this->load->library('upload');

$number_of_files_uploaded = count($_FILES['upl_files']['name']);

for ($i = 0; $i < $number_of_files_uploaded; $i++) :
      $_FILES['userfile']['name']     = $_FILES['upl_files']['name'][$i];
      $_FILES['userfile']['type']     = $_FILES['upl_files']['type'][$i];
      $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'] = $_FILES['upl_files']['tmp_name'][$i];
      $_FILES['userfile']['error']    = $_FILES['upl_files']['error'][$i];
      $_FILES['userfile']['size']     = $_FILES['upl_files']['size'][$i];
      $config = array(
        'file_name'     => <your ouw function to generate random names>,
        'allowed_types' => 'jpg|jpeg|png|gif',
        'max_size'      => 3000,
        'overwrite'     => FALSE,

        /* real path to upload folder ALWAYS */
        'upload_path'
            => $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/path/to/upload/folder'
      );
      $this->upload->initialize($config);
      if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload()) :
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
      else :
        $final_files_data[] = $this->upload->data();
        // Continue processing the uploaded data
      endif;
    endfor;
  }
```

Now with this $final_files_data - you can do your further processing.